# Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

```
Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the
last "terraform apply":

  # google_bigquery_table.Changelog_History has changed
  ~ resource "google_bigquery_table" "Changelog_History" {
        id                  = "projects/projectIdxxx/datasets/xxxx/tables/Changelog_History"
      ~ last_modified_time  = 1640178193905 -> 1640246970955
      ~ num_bytes           = 19225622 -> 20160982
      ~ num_rows            = 56783 -> 59550
        # (14 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }
```

Every time i run terraform apply, it outputs this kind of an output for all our bigquery tables.
It is obvious that num_rows has changed outside of terraform.
It this expected behavior? How should I deal with it?

I read that lifecycle -> ignore_changes might solve it if explicitly set to ignore.
But it is strange that I need to do it.

We use terraform version 1.1.0

Comment: By default Terraform will detect any changes in the infrastructure. So yeah, if you want to ignore new rows in the table, just ignore them with the lifecycle trick.

Comment: And btw, there is a somewhat critical bug in 1.1.0, so you should upgrade Terraform to 1.1.2: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases